# how to insert .txt file data into database using php?

Tags: php

I have been inserting .txt file data in my sql-server database using php which is working too but I am getting undefined array error please help me in resolving the same

.txt data

```
ankit,ankit@gmail.com

swapnil, swapnil@gmail.com

shefali, shefali@gmail.com

abhishek, abhishek@gmail.com
```

my php code for implementing the same

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';


$open = fopen('employee.txt','r');

while (!feof($open)) 
{
    $getTextLine = fgets($open);
    $explodeLine = explode(",",$getTextLine);
    
    list($name,$email) = $explodeLine;
    
    $qry = "insert into employees (name,email) values('".$name."','".$email."')";

 $run =     sqlsrv_query($conn,$qry);
}

fclose($open);

?>
```

// sql table query

```
CREATE TABLE employees(name VARCHAR(255) ,email VARCHAR(255) );
```

// Error which i am getting

> Warning: Undefined array key 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mainfileupload\filetesting.php on line 18
>
> Warning: Undefined array key 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mainfileupload\filetesting.php on line 18
>
> Warning: Undefined array key 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mainfileupload\filetesting.php on line 18

Comment: Are there blank lines in your file? Or lines where the `,` is missing?

Comment: *getting undefined array error* It is not an *error* it is a warning

Comment: @Jens OK but any idea how can i resolve this warning?

Comment: which line is line *18* in `filetesting.php`?

Comment: list($name,$email) = $explodeLine;

Comment: Í would first check it there is a `,` in the line, if not log a warning and ignore the line

Comment: @Jens i am not getting you can you please explain it again

Comment: The warning says, that you have no `,` in a `$getTextLine` so it can not be splitted in two parts and assigned to two variables.

Comment: @Jens but i do have , in my .txt file

Comment: Somethink like `if (!str_contains( $getTextLine ,',')) {echo "$getTextLine has no ,"; continue;}`

Comment: Maybe there are blank lines at the end?

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem. Why not dump `$getTextLine` to check what's in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better check the line to be "non-blank" before executing query. (e.g. check whether $getTextLine is an empty string first)

So change your **while block** to

```
while (!feof($open)) 
{
    $getTextLine = fgets($open);
 
    if (trim($getTextLine)!="") {
      $explodeLine = explode(",",$getTextLine);
      list($name,$email) = $explodeLine;    
      $qry = "insert into employees (name,email) values('".$name."','".$email."')";
      $run = sqlsrv_query($conn,$qry);
     }
}
```

Comment: And if the line is not empty? e.g. there is only a name in the line. I guess the same warning is upcomming

Answer (score -1):

That warning issue represent to pass array variable at sqlsrv_query method & also remove unnecessary blank line at employee.txt

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO employees (name, email) values(?, ?)";
$params = [$name, $email];
$run = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $qry, $params);
if( $run === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

For more reference, please check link
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that this is a problem of any "array variable"? The OP doesn't use prepared statements at all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).